# What is the correct term for testing a classification method on different subsets of the same data

Tags: classification, terminology, methodology, method-comparison

I am searching for the correct definition of a methodology I am using to test the robustness of different classification methods.

I am creating different subsets of the full dataset by cutting away some samples. Each subset is created independently with respect to the others.

Then I run each classification method on every subset.

Finally, I estimate the accuracy of each method considering the classification of the common samples between subsets and full dataset. I calculate the accuracy for each sample as the ratio between the number of correct classification (on subsets with respect to the full dataset classification) and the total number of classification (on subsets).

Example:

```
Classification-full     1    2    3    2    1    1    2

Classification-subset1  1    2         2    3    1   
Classification-subset2       2    3         1    1    2
...

Accuracy                1    1    1    1  0.5    1    1
```

Is there a correct name to this methodology?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to me multiple classification methods are tangential to the problem at hand. Can we assume we have one classifier? Now, lets say you split the dataset into 3 subsets. Then what do you do? (sorry, this part was not clear to me)

Comment: Hi @Theja, I updated the question. Yes I use the same classifier (e.g. a gene signature) for all methods and dataset. The classifier is taken as input by methods as dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)), because I resample with replacement the dataset and then I compute accuracy over the different resamples, using as reference the full dataset.

Can someone tell if it is the correct term for this experimental design?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

K-fold cross validation seems like what you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks.. but does not k-fold cross-validation require that one part of the dataset is the training, the other one the validation? I am just cutting away a part of the dataset and running the classification. I have no training or validation sets - but only comparing the two results. Is this cross-validation?

Comment: K-fold uses your entire data as training and entire data as validation, but not at one go. For example, 3-fold CV demarcate your data into 3 parts. Use random 2 parts to train, test on the 3rd on. Repeat this so you use all parts as training and validation. Your final result is then an average of performance in each iteration. If this is what you are doing, then K-fold cross validation is what you are looking for. If not, then ignore my input.

Comment: Sorry, @ArunJose, I probably wrote the question in a misleading way. I'll correct my question. I intended to say that, I have my full dataset as a reference. Then, I create $n$ datasets by cutting away some samples from each. Each of these subsets is created independently with respect to the others. Then I compare the classification of the common samples between the full dataset and the each one of the subsets.